# How to Deactivate "Enter Key" when using jQueryUI Dialog Confirmation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having some issue with the enter key within IE6 together with the jQuery UI Dialog confirmation box that has just an "Ok" button on it.

```
$("#myBox").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            position:  ["center", 100],
            buttons: {
              'Ok': function() { 
                      $(this).dialog("close"); 
                      closeReq();
                    }
        }
    });
```

Basically, I only want the dialog box together with any additional function calls against the "Ok" to close/fire function, only when the user clicks on the "Ok" button.

At the moment, I allow the user to press the "Enter" to fire off the retrieval of some info and then based on some validation of this data, I produce a modal jQuery UI dialog box but seems to autmatically close from the user's pressing of the "Enter Key" from the start.

How can I prevent this from occuring, i.e. deactivate the "Enter" key in IE6 for this jQueryUI Dialog Message box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> At the moment, I allow the user to press the "Enter" to fire off the retrieval of some info and then based on some validation of this data

whereever you do that, call

```
.preventDefault();
.stopPropagation();
```

within your event handler. Returning `false` is like a shortcut for that.

Comment: sorry jAndy, didn't work for me. By still pressing enter, goes through the motions and also removes the dialog without allowing the user to acknowledge the "OK" button. Is there anything in the buttons that can be done?

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry for the delay in getting back but I managed to solve this issues using the following logic:     if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
      }

Answer (score 1):

Managed to track this down which solved my problem, please refer to
[this solution](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/482145-preventdefault-not-recognized-ie6).

Looks like preventDefault is not recognized by IE6.

Thanks to @jAndy for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Good you solved your problem. Here what worked for me:

```
// Kills an event's propagation and default action. Scott Andrew
function knackerEvent(eventObject) {
    if (eventObject && eventObject.stopPropagation) {
        eventObject.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (window.event && window.event.cancelBubble ) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    if (eventObject && eventObject.preventDefault) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
    }
    if (window.event) {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```